# MacBook Pro Locked out at Boot

Tags: linux, boot, macbook-pro, password-recovery, password-protection

My MacBook pro is asking for a password the second I turn the computer on, and no password makes it go away. Is there any way to bypass this, or get Linux to work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the firmware password prompt. On older Macs, you could reset the firmware password by changing the RAM config (temporarily removing a DIMM). On modern Macs, I believe you have to take it to Apple and show proof of ownership.